# Create DataFrame from dict with lists as values

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary and want to transform it into a data frame. For reasons that are not important, the data frame must exist prior to the operation on an empty state so Im using this code:

```
dfResult =  pd.DataFrame()
d={}
d['p1']=123
d['p2']='foo'
#d['p3']= [10,10]
df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=[0]) #index is irrelevant
```

I works fine, except when one of the values is a list when it fails with this message:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (1)
```

any idea how can I fix that problem?

thanks

Comment: You should drop the  index=[0], since d['p3'] is two dimensional, python will generate the index acordingly, you can then modify it by using df.index = newIndex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can specify column name:

```
d={}
d['p1']=123
d['p2']='foo'
d['p3']= [10,10]
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':d})
print (df)
         col
p1       123
p2       foo
p3  [10, 10]
```

Or is possible create `Series`:

```
s = pd.Series(d)
print (s)
p1         123
p2         foo
p3    [10, 10]
dtype: object
```

Also for me `DataFrame` constructor works, but list values are converted to scalars:

```
d={}
d['p1']=123
d['p2']='foo'
d['p3']= [10,5]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print (df)
    p1   p2  p3
0  123  foo  10
1  123  foo   5
```

If need columns names is possible use [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) and transpose by [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').T
print (df)
    p2        p3   p1
0  foo  [10, 10]  123
```

Or is possible use dict comprehension for nested `list`s:

```
print ({k:[v] for k,v in d.items()})
{'p2': ['foo'], 'p3': [[10, 10]], 'p1': [123]}

df = pd.DataFrame({k:[v] for k,v in d.items()})
print (df)
    p1   p2        p3
0  123  foo  [10, 10]
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply but the "ps" are supposed to be columns, not rows....and your last example produces two rows

Answer (score 1):

```
dfResult =  pd.DataFrame()
d={}
d['p1']=123
d['p2']='foo'
d['p3']= [10,10]
d = {k:[v] if type(v) is list else v for k,v in d.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=[0]) #index is irrelevant
```

then it will work